# Unusual behavior from shelve.keys() in python 3.3

Tags: python, python-3.x, shelve

I have a short shelve practice program that runs as expected in python 2.7.  I moved it over to 3.3, as such:

```
import shelve

db = shelve.open('lib')
db['a'] = "string1"
db['b'] = "string2"
keylist = db.keys()
print( keylist )
db.close()
```

Now I get this result (not exactly an error, but not the desired behavior:

```
KeysView(<shelve.DbfilenameShelf object at 0x7f0f06b3be90>)
```

Any ideas on what is going wrong and how to fix it?  Did something change in shelve for 3.3?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`shelve` is meant to behave like a `dict` which has changed... In Python 2.x `dict`'s use to return a list when `.keys()` was called, in Python 3.x it returns a view object of the keys. If you want the actual keys, you have to materialise them to a `list`:

```
keylist = list(db.keys())
```